# Imagem no select

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Tenho um select de idiomas e gostaria de deixar bandeiras no lugar das palavras, andei pesquisando e vi que isto não e possível, teria que refazer o select usando div e span.
Minha duvida é como faço isso.

```
<div class="idiomaescolha1">
  <select ng-model="vm.form.produto.idioma1" id="idioma1" class="campoHora input-lg">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="POR" style="background-image:url('./XN3hWOM.png');" aria-hidden="true">{{'MSG.PORTUGUES'| translate}}</option>
    <option value="ESP" style="background-image:url('/assets/images/flags/4x3/es.svg');" aria-hidden="true">{{'MSG.ESPANHOL'| translate}}</option>
    <option value="ING" style="background-image:url('/assets/images/flags/4x3/us.svg');" aria-hidden="true">{{'MSG.INGLES'| translate}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Sua duvida é como fazer com `div` ou `span`? tem que ser em modo `select`?

Comment: A principio como fazer com divs e spans, mas se tivesse algum modo com o próprio select vai ser ate melhor.

Comment: Só no `Firefox`, para ter suporte a todos os navegadores terá que usar sim `div`

Comment: E como eu faria para fazer isto com `div`, meu principal problema é o uso do `ng-model`.

Comment: Por que o uso do `ng-model`?

Comment: Eu não uso `angular`, mas uso `vue`, vou te dar um exemplo baseado, e você adapta conforme sua necessidade, qualquer dificuldade me fala que tento te ajudar.

Comment: Pois se o servidor me devolver um idioma o select vai ser preenchido automaticamente e vai ser desabilitado, senão devolver nada o usuário vai ter a opção de editar o idioma.

Comment: Da uma olhada na minha resposta, achei diversas formas mas tentei compartilhar a que considerei mais fácil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pesquisei e encontrei diversas formas de fazer isso, vou colocar aqui a que achei mais prática, utilizando `HTML`, `CSS`, `JQuery`.

Referência com tutorial: [Reinventing a drop down with css and jquery](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/reinventing-a-drop-down-with-css-and-jquery/)

Basicamente você vai utilizar `<a>` e `<span>` para exibição do seu "select" e ao final atribuir o valor selecionado a um `<input type="hidden" />` para poder manipular a vontade e submeter para o server-side.

Segue abaixo exemplo funcionando:

```js
$(".dropdown img.flag").addClass("flagvisibility");

$(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
});

$(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
    $("#idiomaSelecionado").val(
      getSelectedValue("sample")
    );
    
    console.log(
      'Idioma selecionado:' + getSelectedValue("sample")
    );
});

function getSelectedValue(id) {
    return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
        $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

$(".dropdown img.flag").toggleClass("flagvisibility");
```

```css
body { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; font-size:0.75em; color:#000;}
        .desc { color:#6b6b6b;}
        .desc a {color:#0092dd;}
        
        .dropdown dd, .dropdown dt, .dropdown ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
        .dropdown dd { position:relative; }
        .dropdown a, .dropdown a:visited { color:#816c5b; text-decoration:none; outline:none;}
        .dropdown a:hover { color:#5d4617;}
        .dropdown dt a:hover { color:#5d4617; border: 1px solid #d0c9af;}
        .dropdown dt a {background:#e4dfcb url('http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/reinventing-drop-down/arrow.png') no-repeat scroll right center; display:block; padding-right:20px;
                        border:1px solid #d4ca9a; width:150px;}
        .dropdown dt a span {cursor:pointer; display:block; padding:5px;}
        .dropdown dd ul { background:#e4dfcb none repeat scroll 0 0; border:1px solid #d4ca9a; color:#C5C0B0; display:none;
                          left:0px; padding:5px 0px; position:absolute; top:2px; width:auto; min-width:170px; list-style:none;}
        .dropdown span.value { display:none;}
        .dropdown dd ul li a { padding:5px; display:block;}
        .dropdown dd ul li a:hover { background-color:#d0c9af;}
        
        .dropdown img.flag { border:none; vertical-align:middle; margin-left:10px; }
        .flagvisibility { display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<dl id="sample" class="dropdown idiomaescolha1">
    <dt><a href="#"><span>Selecione</span></a></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
           <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img class="flag" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/206/206597.png" alt="" width="16" height="16" />
              <span class="value">POR</span>
              Português
            </a>
           </li>
           <li>
              <a href="#">
                <img class="flag" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/206/206724.png" alt="" width="16" height="16" />
                <span class="value">ESP</span>
                Espanhol
              </a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img class="flag" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/206/206626.png" alt="" width="16" height="16" />
              <span class="value">ING</span>
              Inglês
            </a>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
<input type="hidden" id="idiomaSelecionado" value="" />
```

Comment: Otimo, exatamente isto, agora vou tentar alterar para habilitar a edição ou autocompletar.

Comment: Que bom que ajudou, se você impacar na edição, abre uma nova pergunta que eu ou outros usuários te ajudaremos.